# Access is denied exception while running autoit exe file from selenium java code

Tags: exception, webdriver, autoit

In my selenium webdriver code i am calling an autoit exe for handling an windows authentication dialog . But when i execute the code it it throwing exception

the code is

```
try {
            String s2 = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            String path2 = s2 + "\\src\resources\\AuthHandler.exe";

            java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().getRuntime().exec(path2);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exception is

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "D:\ProjCode\workspace\xxxx\src": CreateProcess error=5, Access is
>   denied

What might be the reason for this . i tried

> Process p = new ProcessBuilder(path2).start();
>   but getting the same result .

The exe is having execute privilege, when i double click it, it is working fine .

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        String s2 = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String[] myEXEpath =  new String[]{ s2 + "\\src\\resources\\"+"MyExe.exe","firefox" };
        java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().getRuntime().exec(myEXEpath);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```